# How to covert string to date?

Tags: ios, swift

my string value is "2021.09.28 23:39".

but converted date is Optional(2021-09-28 14:39:00 +0000)

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ko_kr")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "KST")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2021.09.28 23:39")
let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date!)
```

Comment: You are successfully converting the string to its date equivalent and getting the right answer, so what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working correctly.

The KST timezone is UTC +9.

So... a time of `23:39` in the time zone KST is the same moment in time as the time `14:39` in UTC.

You output of `Optional(2021-09-28 14:39:00 +0000)` shows the timezone of `+0000` and so is a displayed as a UTC time.